# ex_aws_sts AssumeRoleWebIdentityAdapter crashes ex_aws with process attempted to call itself

Tags: elixir, amazon-sqs, aws-sts

This call: ExAws.SQS.get_queue_url(queue) |> ExAws.request(debug_requests: true)

results in this crash. Using ex_aws_sts, and ex_aws at version 2.2

config :ex_aws,
access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, {:awscli, "default", 30}, :instance_role],
secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}, {:awscli, "default", 30}, :instance_role],
security_token: [{:system, "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"}, :instance_role],
awscli_auth_adapter: ExAws.STS.AuthCache.AssumeRoleWebIdentityAdapter,

```
2021-07-20 21:26:26.761 pid=<0.2408.0> [info]  Application d_loader exited: exited in: DLoader.Application.start(:normal, [])
```

12
** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(ExAws.Config.AuthCache, {:refresh_awscli_config, "default", 30000}, 30000)
11
** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(ExAws.Config.AuthCache, {:refresh_auth, %{access_key_id: "dummy", host: "sts.us-west-1.amazonaws.com", http_client: ExAws.Request.Hackney, json_codec: Jason, normalize_path: true, port: 443, region: "us-west-1", retries: [max_attempts: 10, base_backoff_in_ms: 10, max_backoff_in_ms: 10000], role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::981971132015:role/doc_loader_pod_role_qa", role_session_name: "default_session", scheme: "https://", secret_access_key: "dummy", security_token: [{:system, "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"}, :instance_role], web_identity_token: "eyJhb...vq-Q"}}, 30000)
10
** (EXIT) process attempted to call itself
9
21:26:26.760 [error] gen_server 'Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache' terminated with reason: {calling_self,{'Elixir.GenServer',call,['Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache',{refresh_auth,#{access_key_id => <<"dummy">>,host => <<"sts.us-west-1.amazonaws.com">>,http_client => 'Elixir.ExAws.Request.Hackney',json_codec => 'Elixir.Jason',normalize_path => true,port => 443,region => <<"us-west-1">>,retries => [{max_attempts,10},{base_backoff_in_ms,10},{max_backoff_in_ms,10000}],role_arn => <<"arn:aws:iam::981971132015:role/doc_loader_pod_role_qa">>,role_session_name => <<"default_session">>,scheme => ...,...}},...]}} in 'Elixir.GenServer':call/3 line 1016
8

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fix to ex_aws_sts here: https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_sts/pull/28